# 2D array passing via pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, multidimensional-array

Below is my code, where I'm passing my array named a to a display function which will just display the array.

I'm getting an `invalid type argument of type unary *` error on this statement `printf("Arr[%d][%d] is %d\n",i,j,*(*(q+i)+j));`

However, the commented code prints the values properly. Can you please explain what wrong am I doing? I'm new to C so forgive me if it's a silly mistake/error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void display(int *, int, int);
int main()
{
    int a[3][4] = {
                            {1,2,3,4},
                            {5,6,7,8},
                            {9,10,11,12}
                            };
    display(a,3,4);
    /*
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<4; j++)
                printf("Arr[%d][%d] is %d\n",i,j,*(*(a+i)+j));
        }
    */
    return 0;
}
void display(int *q, int row, int col)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<col; j++)
                printf("Arr[%d][%d] is %d\n",i,j,*(*(q+i)+j));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, to pass `2D` arrays to functions you need to specify the array dimensions for all but the first dimension, so in this example you need the `[4]` for the last dimension but you can optionally omit it for the first dimension, i.e.

```
void display( int (*q)[4], int row, int col)
```

And make above declaration as follows

```
void display(int (*)[], int, int);
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! But could you please tell me what does (*q) mean? I understand that the last dimension is needed, but what's that (*q) for?

Comment: If you specify the dimension, you don't need the array pointer syntax. `void display( int q[][4], int row, int col)` might be easier to read.

Comment: @Lundin yes no need. And also `void display( int q[][4], int row, int col)` is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to solve this would be to explicitly pass the array's address and de-reference it (`display()`) the desired result however can also be achieved without the additional level of indirection (`display1()`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(const size_t row, const size_t col, int (*pa)[row][col]);
void display1(const size_t row, const size_t col, int a[row][col]);

int main(void)
{
  int a[3][4] = {
    {  1,  2,  3,  4 },
    {  5,  6,  7,  8 },
    {  9, 10, 11, 12 } 
  };

  display(3, 4, &a);
  display1(3, 4, a);

  return 0;
}

void display(const size_t rows, const size_t cols, const int (*pa)[row][col]);
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
    {
      printf("Arr[%zu][%zu] is %d\n", i, j, (*pa)[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

void display1(const size_t rows, const size_t cols, const int a[row][col]);
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
  {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
    {
      printf("Arr[%zu][%zu] is %d\n", i, j, a[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

*Update*: This needs at least a C99 compatible compiler.

Comment: Just one indirection too much, to my taste.

Comment: Seem's like a much cleaner way, ty!

Answer (score 1):

In modern C you should pass the sizes of the dimensions first

```
void display(size_t row, size_t col, int (*q)[col]);
```

and you then can use `q` just as normal as `q[i][j]` with all index computations done for you.

```
void display(size_t row, size_t col, int (*q)[col]) {
    for(size_t i=0; i<row; i++) {
            for(size_t j=0; j<col; j++)
                printf("Arr[%zu][%zu] is %d\n", i, j, q[i][j]);
        }
}
```

This needs at leas C99 to work.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with that way of accessing elements (q[i][j]), however I wish to learn to do so using pointers. Thank you for pointing out how to pass 2d array as (*q)[col] :)

Comment: But the only thing here that's C99-dependent is the variable declarations inside the loop? Which is unrelated to the problem: the array pointer syntax should work on any version of C. The col array size of the array pointer seems to be ignored at least by gcc -std=c89.

Comment: Nevermind, `-pedantic-errors` made gcc behave as it should. Funny that `gcc -std=c89` allows you to use VLA:s.

Answer (score 0):

Your only problem was with the way you were calling display. You needed to drop the indexes when passing the array and fix the initial definition for display to match:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(int q[][4], int, int);

int main()
{
    int a[3][4] = {
                            {1,2,3,4},
                            {5,6,7,8},
                            {9,10,11,12}
                            };

    display (a, 3, 4);

    return 0;
}
void display(int q[][4], int row, int col)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<col; j++)
                printf("Arr[%d][%d] is %d\n",i,j,*(*(q+i)+j));
        }
}
```

Output:

```
Arr[0][0] is 1
Arr[0][1] is 2
Arr[0][2] is 3
Arr[0][3] is 4
Arr[1][0] is 5
Arr[1][1] is 6
Arr[1][2] is 7
Arr[1][3] is 8
Arr[2][0] is 9
Arr[2][1] is 10
Arr[2][2] is 11
Arr[2][3] is 12
```